# Error between HSQLDB local data base connectio and my project in IntelliJ IDEA . However, when I use Data Base UI Manager it is running well

Tags: java, intellij-idea, hsqldb

I recently update to IntelliJ IDEA 15 and when I'm trying to run the main() class which connects to DB I get this error:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\bin\java" -Didea.launcher.port=7532 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 15.0.1\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Users\David\git\isw\out\production\LloguerVehicles;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 15.0.1\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain proves.persistencia.TestDAOs
Exception in thread "main" excepciones.DAOExcepcion: org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver
    at persistencia.dao.ReservaDAO.<init>(ReservaDAO.java:27)
    at proves.persistencia.TestReserva.<init>(TestReserva.java:14)
    at proves.persistencia.TestDAOs.main(TestDAOs.java:18)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

It appers to be a DB driver error but I cannot understand how to solve it.

Now I always get this other error: =(

```
[S1000][-451] Database lock acquisition failure: lockFile: org.hsqldb.persist.LockFile@5270e6db[file =C:\Users\David\git\isw\LloguerVehicles\data\alquilervehiculosBD.lck, exists=true, locked=false, valid=false, ] method: checkHeartbeat read: 2015-11-13 21:27:47 heartbeat - read: -7811 ms.
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: Database lock acquisition failure: lockFile: org.hsqldb.persist.LockFile@5270e6db[file =C:\Users\David\git\isw\LloguerVehicles\data\alquilervehiculosBD.lck, exists=true, locked=false, valid=false, ] method: checkHeartbeat read: 2015-11-13 21:27:47 heartbeat - read: -7811 ms.
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.persist.LockFile.newLockFileLock(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.persist.Logger.acquireLock(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.persist.Logger.open(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Database.reopen(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Database.open(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.DatabaseManager.getDatabase(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.DatabaseManager.newSession(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.intellij.database.remote.jdbc.impl.RemoteDriverImpl.connect(RemoteDriverImpl.java:27)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:323)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$256(TCPTransport.java:683)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0):

The first error can be fixed by including the hsqldb.jar in your project library list.

The second error is raised because you have already connected to the database from a different Java process using the `jdbc:hsqldb:file:` connection url.

For development, it is best to run an HSQLDB Server separate from your dev environment. You can then connect to this server at the same time from different programs.